# Passing bootstrapped variables and JSON to require.js

Tags: javascript, requirejs

What is the best practice for passing bootstrapped variables within the rendered page (i.e. JSON data or config variables) to `require.js` so they can be checked for an used by dependancies?

It looks like this could be done by checking the `window` object (i.e. `window.bootstrapped_models` but that does not seem very optimal.

`app.html` - example data within the HTML document

```
<script>
var config = {
    "isAdmin": true,
    "userId": 1
};
var bootstrapped_models = {
    "groups": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Foo"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Bar"
        }
    ]
}
</script>
```

`app.js` - example app using require()

```
require(['jquery', 'GroupCollection'], function($, GroupCollection) {

    // extend default config
    if (config) {
        $.extend(defaults, config);
    }

    // use bootstrapped JSON here
    var collection = new GroupCollection;
    if (bootstrapped_models.groups.length > 0) {
        collection.add(bootstrapped_models.groups);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 6):

The answer from @timDunham was helpful, but it felt a little overly complicated to me. Playing around with require.js and Lithium (PHP MVC) I came up with the following. It's simple and has worked in each instance I've run into.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
define('bootstrapData', function () {
    return <?php echo json_encode($bootstrapData) ?>;
});
</script>
```

Which is then available by doing the following:

```
define(['bootstrapData'], function(bootstrapData) {
    console.log(bootstrapData); // Will output your bootstrapped object
});
```

Obviously the way I'm bringing the data in is language specific, but the rest should be useful regardless of your situation.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work with optimizing my js...I tried using excludeShallow with the boostrapData module but when I went to compile it still tried to find a bootstrapData file. Can anyone explain how they got it to work? I'm pretty new to require.js. Also, I'm using require version 1.0.1 (in case that makes a difference)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if my method is best practice but I do something a lot like what you are doing except instead of butting the bootstrapped models on the global object, I create a define for it in my HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    define("bootstrappedModelJson", function() {
        return @Html.Action("Controller", "RenderModel");
    });

    require({
        baseUrl: //etc.
    }, ["app"],
    function(){

    });
</script>
```

then I have a js file called `current.model` that can be required by other modules and looks like this:

```
define(
[
    'require',
    'model'
],
function (require, Model)
{
    var json= require("bootstrappedModelJson");

    return new Model(json);   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve problems with optimize/build by disabling the bootstrapData in your build.js 
Like this:

```
paths: {
    bootstrapData: "empty:",
```